# Why does Sequelize findByPk load a Date column as string

Tags: date, sequelize.js

I have a model with a field of type `Date | null`. The MySQL database column is type `date`.

```
@Column
my_date: Date | null
```

When I load an object with `findByPk` the field is a `string`.

```
console.log(typeof myObject.my_date) // 'string'
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this how Sequelize is supposed to work?

Note: if I change the database column type to `datetime`, it is loaded as a `Date` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sequelize v5.22.4

In `/lib/data-types.js`, `_sanitize` outputs a string. So it looks like the correct data type for the property is `string`, not `date`.

```
/**
 * A date only column (no timestamp)
 */
class DATEONLY extends ABSTRACT {
  toSql() {
    return 'DATE';
  }
  _stringify(date) {
    return moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  }
  _sanitize(value, options) {
    if ((!options || options && !options.raw) && !!value) {
      return moment(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    }
    return value;
  }
  _isChanged(value, originalValue) {
    if (originalValue && !!value && originalValue === value) {
      return false;
    }
    // not changed when set to same empty value
    if (!originalValue && !value && originalValue === value) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```